# Error in Android Studio While Building My App After Removing Fusepowered SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having this problem error, can anyone solve it. This my Code of AndroidManifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zikatv.zikatvlive"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <!-- Recommended permissions to receive brand‐centric ads with interactive functionality for better eCPMs -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />

    <!-- GCM -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission
        android:name="[APPLICATION PACKAGE].permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.zikatv.zikatvlive.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zikatv.zikatvlive.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zikatv.zikatvlive.CategoryItemActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zikatv.zikatvlive.SingleChannelActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zikatv.zikatvlive.Search"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zikatv.zikatvlive.AboutActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zikatv.zikatvlive.ReportChannelActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zikatv.zikatvlive.TvPlay"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>

        <!-- AdColony -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <!-- Don't forgot InitActivity -->
        <activity
            android:name="io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|navigation"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <!-- for start app -->

        <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.list3d.List3DActivity"
            android:taskAffinity="com.livetv.zoongatv.AppWall"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.AppWallActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:taskAffinity="com.livetv.zoongatv.AppWall"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <!-- Required Activity for rendering ads in the embedded browser -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.inmobi.rendering.InMobiAdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <!-- Required Receiver for enhanced targeting for better ads. -->

        <receiver
            android:name="com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.inmobi.share.id" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.inmobi.signals.activityrecognition.ActivityRecognitionManager"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity android:name="com.avocarrot.androidsdk.VideoActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.revmob.FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.revmob.app.id"
            android:value="5708e90e978e09ae7b2ff92b" />

        <service android:name="com.appnext.core.DownloadService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.appnext.ads.interstitial.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.appnext.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <!-- Required Activity for playback of Vungle video ads -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.vungle.publisher.FullScreenAdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <!-- AdTapsy START -->

        <receiver
            android:name="com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.inmobi.share.id" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- Applovin Activities -->
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity" />

        <!-- AdTapsy END -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Proguard:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.4.0.jar')
    compile project(':InitActivity')
    compile files('libs/StartAppInApp-3.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/InMobi-5.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/avocarrot-sdk-v.3.6.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/revmob.jar')
    compile files('libs/adcolony.jar')
    compile files('libs/AppnextAndroidSDK.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile files('libs/dagger-2.1.jar')
}
```

And this is the screenshot of error
[image]

and one other thing when i delete the code of AndroidManifest mentioned below in the image and clean or build the project or sync, it appears again,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

in your manifest under 
remove your permission tag with

```
<permission
android:name = "com.android.application.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

> and when you build the app and after getting errors the manifest which
>   shows up is a non editable manifest the changes you will make in it
>   wont be saved. You should open your manifest manually from project and remove
>   whatever you want to remove.